# Getting id of checkboxes selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to get the id's of the checkboxes with the class `file-selection-id`. The checkbox is inside a for loop which is why I have placed variables on the id's and names.

```
<input class="file-selection-id" type="checkbox" value="" name="file<?php echo $i; ?>_<?php echo $t; ?>" id="file<?php echo $i; ?>_<?php echo $t; ?>">
```

What I want is that when I click a button, it would get all of the id's of the selected checkboxes.

```
$('.move-file-buttons').click( 
function(event) { 
  //??? 
$('input:checkbox.file-selection-id').each(function () {

  });
     });
```

But I don't know how to get the Id's of all the checkboxes that were on the file-selection-id class that I need? What could be ways on how I could call the ID's of the checkboxes(for example if I had 4 checkboxes with 2 selections)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var arr = $('input:checkbox.file-selection-id').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

---

if you want `id` of `checked` check-boxes

```
var arr = $('input:checkbox.file-selection-id').filter(':checked').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

---

```
var arr = $('input:checkbox.file-selection-id:checked').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

---

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)